# mutate a column with 3 groups - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I mutate a new column with different names based on existing column?

data

```
index value
a 2
b 3
c 2
d 5
```

output

```
index value type
a 2 good
b 3 bad
c 2 good
d 5 exceptional
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `value` is the existing column that would determine `type`. You can use `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(type = case_when(value == 2 ~ "good", 
                          value == 3 ~ "bad", 
                          value == 5 ~ "exceptional")
```