# How to add a new column with values specific to grouped variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm new to R and have found similar solutions to my problem, but I'm struggling to apply these to my code. Please help...

These data are simplified, as the id variables are many:

```
df = data.frame(id = rep(c("a_10", "a_11", "b_10", "b_11"), each = 5),
           site = rep(1:5, 4),
           value = sample(1:20))
```

The aim is to add another column labelled "year" with values that are grouped by "id" but the true names are many - so I'm trying to simplify the code by using the ending digits.

I can use `dplyr` to split the dataframe into each id variable using this code (repeated for each id variable):

```
df %>% 
  select(site, id, value) %>% 
  filter(grepl("10$", id)) %>% 
  mutate(Year = "2010")`
```

Rather than using `merge` to re-combine the dataframes back into one, is there not a more simple method?

I tried modifying `case_when` with `mutate` as described in a previous answer:

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/63043920/12313457][1]

```
mutate(year = case_when(grepl(c("10$", "11$", id) == c("2010", "2011"))))
```

is something like this possible??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your `id` column has different string lengths you can use `sub`:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(Year = paste0("20", sub('^.*_(\\d+)$', '\\1', id)))
#>      id site value Year
#> 1  a_10    1     2 2010
#> 2  a_10    2     7 2010
#> 3  a_10    3    16 2010
#> 4  a_10    4    10 2010
#> 5  a_10    5    11 2010
#> 6  a_11    1     5 2011
#> 7  a_11    2    13 2011
#> 8  a_11    3    14 2011
#> 9  a_11    4     6 2011
#> 10 a_11    5    12 2011
#> 11 b_10    1    17 2010
#> 12 b_10    2     1 2010
#> 13 b_10    3     4 2010
#> 14 b_10    4    15 2010
#> 15 b_10    5     9 2010
#> 16 b_11    1     8 2011
#> 17 b_11    2    20 2011
#> 18 b_11    3    19 2011
#> 19 b_11    4    18 2011
#> 20 b_11    5     3 2011
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Maybe a simpler regex..`sub('.*_', '', id)`

Comment: Thanks - this works on the simplified data but not when applied to the real dataset (the id names are many and vary in length). 

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `Year =
  paste0("20", sub(".*_", "", id))`.
Caused by error in `as.character()`:
! cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Hence, why I was hoping for a simple solution within dplyr etc. I don't have permission to share the real data but editing the id labels may be closer to my problem `id = rep(c("abc_10", "abcde_11", "bdfc_10", "b_11"), each = 5)`

Comment: @Paul the solution works just as well for those labels. Are you sure your column in the real data is actually called `id` (as opposed to say `ID`)?

Comment: That's hilarious - I didn't change the column name! Thank you @AllanCameron
it works great :D

Comment: out of interest, what does the code actually tell R to do?

Comment: As you are using `sub`, can also add the replacement `df %>% mutate(Year = sub(".*_", '20', id))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substr` to get the final two digits of `id` and then `paste0` this to "20" to recreate the year.

```r
df |> dplyr::mutate(Year = paste0("20", substr(id, 3, 4)))
#>      id site value Year
#> 1  a_10    1     5 2010
#> 2  a_10    2    12 2010
#> 3  a_10    3     9 2010
#> 4  a_10    4     7 2010
#> 5  a_10    5    13 2010
#> 6  a_11    1     3 2011
#> 7  a_11    2     4 2011
#> 8  a_11    3    16 2011
#> 9  a_11    4     2 2011
#> 10 a_11    5     6 2011
#> 11 b_10    1    19 2010
#> 12 b_10    2    14 2010
#> 13 b_10    3    15 2010
#> 14 b_10    4    10 2010
#> 15 b_10    5    11 2010
#> 16 b_11    1    18 2011
#> 17 b_11    2     1 2011
#> 18 b_11    3    20 2011
#> 19 b_11    4    17 2011
#> 20 b_11    5     8 2011
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>